# How can I get data from RabbitMQ? I don't want consume it from queue

Tags: rabbitmq, mnesia

Is there a tool can view  data from queue? I just want know what data in queue, but I don't want consume these data. Web UI and REST API just show count number, I want details.

How can I use Mnesia query queue's data? like MySQL client.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options

**Firehose**

You may consider firehose feature
https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html

> RabbitMQ has a "firehose" feature, where the administrator can enable
>   (on a per-node, per-vhost basis) an exchange to which publish- and
>   delivery-notifications should be CCed.

**rabbitmq_tracing plugin**

https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html

**Second queue**
Just setup your exchange so it will deliver messages to two queues. One queue is for actual business procesing. Second queue is for debug pourposes only. Reading messages from second queue will consume them. For that debug queue you may enable reasonable TTL and/or Queue Length Limit. Otherwise, unconsumed messages will eventually eat all disk space.

**Consume and re-send**

You may consume message (to see it) and immediatelyre-send same message to  the same queue. RabbitMQ management GUI has this option. Note that this will change order of the messages.

Comment: About the third option, instead of re-publishing the message, it can be rejected (nacked). In this case, it will keep its place in the queue.